# rbind if column contains partial match R

Tags: r

I have a lists of dataframes where I have managed to successfully loop through the lists and merge the tables as I required.
I have done this by something similar to the following code:

```
anno_files<-c("R1000A_v1.hg19_multianno.txt", "R1000B_v1.hg19_multianno.txt" ,"R1000C_v1.hg19_multianno.txt", "RC1080A_v1.hg19_multianno.txt", "RC1080B_v1.hg19_multianno.txt" )

cancer_files<-c("R1000A_v1.hg19_multianno.txt.cancervar", "R1000B_v1.hg19_multianno.txt.cancervar" ,"R1000C_v1.hg19_multianno.txt.cancervar", "RC1080A_v1.hg19_multianno.txt.cancervar", "RC1080B_v1.hg19_multianno.txt.cancervar")

# extract the sample names from the whole filename
samples<- c()
# Iterate through each filename
for (filename in anno_files) {
  # Pull out the characters prior to the first '.'
  filename_id <- unlist(strsplit(filename, "\\."))[1]
  # append to sample_names vector
  samples<- c(samples, filename_id)
}

myfilelist <- lapply(anno_files, read.delim,header=T)
myfilelist2<-lapply(cancer_files, read.csv,sep="\t",header=T)

    library(dplyr)
    for (i in 1:length(myfilelist)){
      all_annotation<-left_join(myfilelist[[i]], myfilelist2[[i]], by = c("Chr","Start","End","Ref","Alt"))
      all_annotation$sample_id<-samples[i]
      write.csv(all_annotation, paste("data/",samples[i],".merged.csv",sep = ""))
}
```

I would like to put in an additional line of code to rbind the tables if they have the same first part of the filename/sample name eg rbind tables `"R1000A_v1", "R1000B_v1" ,"R1000C_v1"` as they are from sample R1000 and rbind `"RC1080A_v1", "RC1080B_v1"` as they are from sample RC1080

I have managed to get out a list of the part of the sample name that I want to match:

```
samples2<- c()
# Iterate through each filename
for (filename in samples) {
  # Pull out the characters prior to the first 'underscore'.'
  filename2_id<-unlist(strsplit(filename, "\\_"))[1]
  filename3_id<-substr(filename2_id,1,nchar(filename2_id)-1)
  # append to sample_names vector
  samples2<- unique(c(samples2, filename3_id))
}
samples2
"R1000""RC1080"
```

So now within the all_annoatation loop I need to do something like:

```
for (j in length(samples2)){
if all_annotation$sample_id contains samples2[j] 
rbind
write.csv
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be easily donde with `data.table`.

```
library(data.table)
```

You'll need to change the csv reading line, so each object is loaded as a data.table (if your csv are big, you'll notice this is fast too):

```
# myfilelist <- lapply(anno_files, read.delim,header=T)
myfilelist <- lapply(anno_files, function(x) assign(gsub("(.*)(\\.txt)", "\\1", x), fread(x), .GlobalEnv))

# myfilelist2 <- lapply(cancer_files, read.csv,sep="\t",header=T)
myfilelist2 <- lapply(cancer_files, function(x) assign(gsub("(.*)(\\.txt\\.cancervar)", "\\1", x), fread(x), .GlobalEnv))
```

Once your objects are created, I'll assume that you know what the pattern on the name is, so you can do something like:

```
R100_total = rbindlist(lapply(ls(pattern = "R100"), get))
R1080_total = rbindlist(lapply(ls(pattern = "R1080"), get))
```

**Provided you don't have any other objects named with the same pattern that you don't want to `rbind`**.

Comment: How would I go about looping over a long list of sample names which contain the pattern? I have only included 2 in the example but have over 100. Something like: `for (i in 1:length(samples2)){
samples2[i]_total = rbindlist(lapply(ls(pattern = samples2[i]), get))
}`

Comment: Consider avoiding `assign`, a function to be rarely used in R.

Comment: Thanks. What would you use instead?

Answer (score 1):

I can't really test this without all the files, but I think this is close:

```
for (j in seq_along(samples2)) {
  all_annotation[grepl(samples2[j], samples)]
    temp <- do.call('rbind', all_annotation[grepl(samples2[j], samples)])
    write.csv(temp, paste0(samples2[j], '.csv'))
  }  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider *apply* family solutions (`lapply`, `sapply`, `Map` which is wrapper of  `mapply`) and avoid the bookkeeping required of `for` loops. And to extract needed samples use string pattern functions `gsub` and `grep`. Finally, run `do.call` and `rbind` to stack like named data frames.

```r
anno_files <- c(
    "R1000A_v1.hg19_multianno.txt",
    "R1000B_v1.hg19_multianno.txt",
    "R1000C_v1.hg19_multianno.txt",
    "RC1080A_v1.hg19_multianno.txt",
    "RC1080B_v1.hg19_multianno.txt" 
)
anno_samples <- sapply(strsplit(anno_files, "\\."), `[`, 1)

cancer_files <- c(
    "R1000A_v1.hg19_multianno.txt.cancervar", 
    "R1000B_v1.hg19_multianno.txt.cancervar",
    "R1000C_v1.hg19_multianno.txt.cancervar", 
    "RC1080A_v1.hg19_multianno.txt.cancervar", 
    "RC1080B_v1.hg19_multianno.txt.cancervar"
) 

cancer_samples <- sapply(strsplit(cancer_files, "\\."), `[`, 1)

process_data <- function(txt_file, s_id) {
    data.frame(
        sample_id = s_id,        # FIRST COLUMN
        read.delim(txt_file),
        source = txt_file        # LAST COLUMN
    )
} 

anno_dfs <- Map(process_data, anno_files, anno_samples)
cancer_dfs <- Map(process_data, cancer_files, cancer_samples)

merged_dfs <- Map(
    # BASE R LEFT JOIN
    merge(x, y, by=c("Chr","Start","End","Ref","Alt"), all.x=TRUE),
    anno_dfs,
    cancer_dfs
) |> setNames(   # NEW PIPE AS OF R v4.1.0+
    anno_samples
)

roots <- unique(gsub("[A-Z]\\_.*$", "", anno_samples))
rbind_dfs <- lapply(
    roots,
    function(r) do.call(
        rbind.data.frame, 
        merged_dfs[grep(r, names(merged_dfs))]
    )
)
```